# spring XD: how to create custom http source

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-xd

I need implement custom http source with cross origin: *.

How to do it? [Spring XD Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#_introduction_16)

Need examples

Answer (score 1):

Developing your custom source would require you to have basic knowledge on spring integration. Anyways here is an example:

You would require to write 4 files:

### File 1:

crossoriginsource.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.yourbasepackage"></context:component-scan>
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>

    <!-- The name of the chaannel is output.(Mandatory to have the name as output) -->
    <int:channel id="output"></int:channel>

    <int:inbound-channel-adapter ref="crossOriginHttpCaller" method="makeHttpCall" channel="output"></int:inbound-channel-adapter>
</beans>
```

crossoriginsource.properties

```
info.shortDescription = Gets data from cross origin sources.
options_class = com.yourbasepackage.CrossOriginSourceMetadata
```

CrossOriginSourceMetadata.java

```
package com.yourbasepackage;

public class CrossOriginSourceMetadata {
    // All the module related configurable properties goes here
    // The properties values for which you would like to take then while defining a stream.
}
```

CrossOriginHttpCaller.java

```
@Component
public class CrossOriginHttpCaller {
    public Message<String> makeHttpCall() {
        // your http calling logic goes here
    }
}
```

After you have developed the module, you have to maintain it in a specific folder structure

```
crossoriginsource
    |
    |---config
    |       |--crossoriginsource.xml
    |       |--crossoriginsource.properties
    |
    |---lib
    |    |--jar containing CrossOriginHttpCaller.java and CrossOriginSourceMetadata.java
    |    |--all the other dependent jars for this module
```

Once you are done packaging the application in this structure, you have to copy it to `xd/modules/source`, and you have to define a stream something like

`stream create --name "test" --definition "crossoriginsource | log" --deploy`

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helped, thanks! But need not to sends messages -> need to receive messages. I think need use MessageProducerSupport for this. Is it true?

Answer (score 0):

Need implement MessageProducerSupport.

With response headers:  `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

For example: fork spring-xd-http-extension.

Look NettyHttpInboundChannelAdapter as example.